# Uso de pseudo-elementos ::after em um DIV simulando um INPUT com LABEL - O Pseudo-elemento sobrepõe o cursor. Como fazer para não sobrepor o cursor?

Tags: div, label, pseudo-classes, pseudo-elementos

Eu criei um DIV editável simulando um INPUT com um LABEL usando o pseudo-elemento ::after e a pseudo-classe :empty. O LABEL (que na realidade é um pseudo-elemento ::after com o content igual ao texto do LABEL) inicialmente aparece como um placeholder dentro do DIV e, após o DIV ser clicado e preenchido com algum texto, a pseudo-classe :empty faz com que o LABEL mude de posição e fique acima do DIV (que simula um INPUT). Até ai tudo funcionando bem. O problema é que quando clico no DIV para escrever algo, o cursor fica atrás do LABEL (pseudo-elemento ::after com o content) e o texto que digito aparece atrás também. Gostaria de saber se tem como o cursor ficar acima desse LABEL.

OBS: Eu estou utilizando a classe form-control do Bootstrap para facilitar fazer o DIV simular as características visuais de um INPUT.

```css
div[data-label-anim] {
    position: relative;
}
div[data-label-anim]::after {
    content: attr(data-label-anim);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1em;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    transform: scale(.7);
    transition:
      transform ease-out 150ms,
      bottom ease-out 150ms;
}
div[data-label-anim]:empty::after {
    transform: scale(1);
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div data-label-anim="Nome" name="name" contentEditable=true class="form-control"></div>
```

> Vejam na imagem abaixo que o topo do cursor (apontado pela seta vermelha) aparece de saindo de trás do LABEL.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Coloque `z-index: -1` no `::after` que ele ficará por trás do cursor.

Veja sem o `z-index` (repare que o cursor fica atrás do texto):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora com o `z-index`, repare que o cursor fica em primeiro plano, por cima do texto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]